# Sending props to a React component for a Jest unit test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

In the render part of a component I have the following div:

```
<div className="col-sm-8" >
<input ref='full_link' className="formctrl" name='full_link' type='text'
value={browser.getURL(this.props.params.id)} />
</div>
```

To write a test unit for this component, I tried to shallow render it (`const component = shallow(<myComponent />);`) and it returns this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

So I need to send this props to my component in the test. How should I send `id` from `this.props.params.id` to the shallow render?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just pass the props as you would normally do when using the component:

```
const component = shallow(<myComponent params={{ id: 1 }} />)
```

Don't forget JSX is just a fancier way to do:

```
React.createElement(MyComponent, { params: { id: 1 } });
```

Note: you called your component `myComponent` but in JSX user-defined component names should begin with a capital letter (`MyComponent`), while "normal" elements (such as divs) start with a lowercase letter.